# Electric field of a configuration of five parallel infinite slabs of dieletric materials

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, dielectric

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to proceed in order to calculate the electric field of a configuration of five slabs of dieletric (insulating) material (actually one of those is vacuum).

The image above shows the configuration.[image]

The dark grey material has a charge density given by $\rho(x) = \rho_0 \frac{x}{a}$, where $a = \frac{D}{2}$ is half the width of each slab. The light grey material has charge density $\rho = \rho_0$. The white material is vacuum.

I'm asked for instance to calculate the electric field for $x < a$, i.e., in the region of vacuum. My first thought was to apply Gauss's Law, but I'm not sure how to choose a proper gaussian surface to perform the calculation. If I choose a gaussian surface limited to the region of $|x| < a$, I will get zero net flux of electric field trough it, and it will be useless.

Another option I thought was to use a gaussian surface that includes some of the surface charge density of the dark grey material- similar to what is done to calculate the electric field in a parallel plate capacitor - but what guarantees me that the remaining of the material will not contribute to the electric field, since its charge density is not even constant? (At least this is not a problem for the light grey material, since it has a constant charge density and the electric field from this material on both sides cancel out...)

Anyway, is there anybody who could help with this matter?

Comment: I forget how it works, but I'm pretty sure you need the Electric Displacement Field:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_displacement_field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can proceed similar to what was suggested in the comment. Assuming field varies only in the $x$ direction you will have
$$\nabla\cdot \vec D=\frac{\partial D_{x}(x)}{\partial x}=\rho_{f}(x)$$
Now you know how to solve the above equation in each of the slabs. For instance, since in the white slab the free charge $\rho_{f}=0$ then
$$\frac{\partial D_{x}(x)}{\partial x}=0\rightarrow D_{x}(x)=C_{\rm v}, |x|<a$$
where $C_{\rm v}$ is a constant. For the dark grey region you have
$$\frac{\partial D_{x}(x)}{\partial x}=\frac{\rho_{0}}{a}x\rightarrow D_{x}(x)=\frac{\rho_{0}}{a}\frac{x^{2}}{2}+C_{\rm dg},a<|x|<3a$$
For the light grey region you have
$$\frac{\partial D_{x}(x)}{\partial x}=\rho_{0}\rightarrow D_{x}(x)=\rho_{0}x+C_{\rm lg},3a<|x|<5a$$
Note that the vaccum outside the slabs, i.e., $|x|>5a$ may be solved using the same process above. All is left is calculating the constants using the boundary conditions for $\vec D$ at the boundaries of the slabs. Since the unit vector perpendicular to the surface is $\hat n=\hat x$ and you don't have free surface charge
$$(\vec D_{2}-\vec D_{1})\cdot \hat x=(D_{x_{2}}-D_{x_{1}})=0$$
Finally, once you calculate $\vec D$ in each of the stratified regions, the electric field $\vec E$ may be easily calculated using the constitutive relationship $\vec D=\epsilon \vec E$. I get $C_{\rm v}=0,C_{\rm dg}=\frac{\rho_{0}a}{2}$, and $C_{\rm lg}=2\rho_{0}a$. Please let me know if you have any questions or there are errors.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to invoke reflection symmetry.  For any $x$ coordinate, we should have $|\vec{E}(x)| = |\vec{E}(-x)|$, with the fields at $x$ and $-x$ pointing in opposite directions.  In addition, the electric field cannot have any $y$- or $z$- components by symmetry;  so the electric flux through any surface perpendicular to the $x$-axis will just be the magnitude of the field times the area of the surface.

This means that if we pick a Gaussian surface as a "pillbox" with flat faces at $\pm x$, the electric flux through each of these faces is guaranteed to be the same. This means, in particular, that if we can draw a symmetric pillbox with no net charge enclosed, then the electric flux through each of the two faces will be zero.